# No internet when I change my router

Tags: networking, router, isp, mac-address, dsl

I have a PPPoE DSL connection. I have one router and it connects to ISP and I have internet access. But when I change it with any other router and try to connect it using using the ISP given credentials, it doesn't connect. I cloned the MAC of previous router still it won't connect.

What should I do to connect it?

Edit: I know contacting ISP works but my ISP is an unreliable guy and to get in contact with him is quite a hassle, so I want to figure it out by myself.

Also, if I am changing MAC of my router, how does my ISP know that there is a router change? I think ISP mappings are Username + Password + MAC.

Answer (score 0):

Try and contact your ISP. In my experience they can allow certain routers to connect. Most likely they have to flip a switch on their end or they'll have the solution you are looking for.

Comment: It works but my isp is an unreliable guy and to get in contact with him is quite a hassle, so I want to figure it out by myself.

Comment: Not sure if there is much of anything else you can do. Have you tried unplugging the other router and swapping it with the one in question?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work.

Comment: Next thing I would try is updating the router firmware if needed and if that fails, you might be forced to give your ISP a call. There isn't much you can really do on your own if on their end they have to change the router.